# Id returned 1 exit status - CodeBlocks with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have installed wxWidgets for Code::Blocks, watched a tutorial on YouTube on how to do this, everything seemed fine. I created a new project, but I can't compile. I get an error. This is how a project looks when I create it, and I do not change nothing in it.

Project when I created it

[image]

And here is the error.

> ld.exe cannot find -lwxmsw28u

[image]

Comment: it can't find the library with that name <can't copy paste from image>.   Please don't post pictures of error messages.  Copy/paste the text.

Comment: Follow this [instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/WxWindowsQuickRef) By the way, better use a recent wxWidgets version. wx2.8 is too old,

Comment: I have followed this tutorial 
https://youtu.be/PlOhu1KkTZw

Comment: I'm not going to watch that video just to detect what you have done differently. That's your job.

Comment: Have you added the home directory of wxWidgets to library and include paths.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In order to make it work, you need to go to settings-->Global Variables. My home directory for wxWidgets is `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0-tdmgcc32` and this is compiled with `gcc`.

**Base:** C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0-tdmgcc32

**include:** C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0-tdmgcc32\include (basically where include dir is)

**lib:** C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0-tdmgcc32\lib\gcc_dll (where all your library files (dll,.a or .lib) are located)

**2)** New Project-->wxWidgets project. Here make sure that if you have compiled wxWidgets as monolithic, select *wxWidgets is built as monolithic library*[image]

**3)** go to Project-->Build Options...

Apply the following settings to **Release**. For Debug, `mswu` should be `mswud`. If you compiled wxWidgets with Visual Studio, then instead of `lib/gcc_dll`, you should see `lib/vc_dll`

If you follow the steps and apply them correctly, it should work.

[image]

### Notes:

**1)** if you have not compiled wxWidgets as monolithic, then instead of `libwxmsw31u.a` under lib gcc_dll directory, you might see different names, just include them for now, later on you can be selective.

**2)** `libwxmsw31u.a` is for the release version and `libwxmsw31ud.a` is for Debug version. Make sure, you include correct files in the debug and release versions.