# Warninig when compiling WxWidgets project

Tags: ubuntu, wxwidgets

When compiling WxWidgets programm, I have such warning:

```
16:42:29: Warning: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.8),
and your program used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1010,wx containers,compatible with 2.8).
```

I have WxWidgets 3.0 on other location. If it possible to set up library location to another place?

Comment: please check if you have the same set of compiler options compiling the library and application. The error gives a hint - different ABI.

Comment: I wrote `wx-config --libs` for linker and `wx-config --cxxflags` for compiler. But how to set up to upper version on different location?

Comment: what was you exact configure line building the library and exact line that you are compiling the project? Also, can you build the `minimal` sample from the wxWidgets?

Comment: Since you have two or more wxWidgets libraries with different versions lurking on your system, I suggest you add the libraries and header files manually to your project rather than `wx-config`

Comment: @macroland How I can use it such way?

Comment: This is for CodeBlocks; however, similar rationale follows for most IDEs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157686/id-returned-1-exit-status-codeblocks-with-wxwidgets/42170750#42170750